# MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2538'

Tags: java, ibm-mq

public class PtpReceiver {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        MQEnvironment.hostname = "192.168.120.28:1415";
        MQEnvironment.channel = "SFMS.TO.CBS";
        MQEnvironment.properties.put(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY,
                MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES);
        System.out.println("Q manager");
        MQQueueManager qMgr = new MQQueueManager("GSCBBRQM");
        System.out.println("Q manager11");

    }

    catch (MQException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.completionCode+ ex.reasonCode);
        }
}
```

}

I got the error following:

MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2538'.

Can any one help me for solve this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is JMS code for doing a connection via for WMQ for JMS.  Bhaumik is using WMQ for Java (non JMS).

Bhaumik, you do not specify the port number in the hostname but rather as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        MQEnvironment.hostname = "192.168.120.28";
        MQEnvironment.port     = 1415;
        MQEnvironment.channel  = "SFMS.TO.CBS";
        MQQueueManager qMgr = new MQQueueManager("GSCBBRQM");
    }

    catch (MQException ex) {
        System.out.println("CC="+ex.completionCode + " : RC="+ ex.reasonCode);
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Roger to help me.I have followed your instruction but still error is same, can you have some tutorial for simple queue connecting to the websphere mq. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I think it is necessary to define your connection mode like this:

```
jmsFactory = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(WMQConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER);
jcf = jmsFactory.createConnectionFactory();

// Set the properties
jcf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_HOST_NAME, hostName);
jcf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_PORT, port);
jcf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
jcf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL, channel);

connection = jcf.createConnection();
```

I hope it works.
For more inormation see [this](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/SendMessagesToWebSphereMQ70).

Answer (score 1):

You can try to provide your connection properties as HashTable as follows.

```
  Hashtable<String, Object> mqht = new Hashtable<>();
  mqht.put(MQConstants.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, "199.40.166.193");
  mqht.put(MQConstants.PORT_PROPERTY, 1414); // Port should be as int value, don't use String.
  mqht.put(MQConstants.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, "A2A");

  MQQueueManager qMgr = null;

  try {
     qMgr = new MQQueueManager(queueManager, mqht);
  } catch (MQException ex) {
     System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem can a silly reason, such as application or server not accessible, my debugging approach concluded `telnet` was not happening.

Comment: The issue was that the port was not specified correctly.  `MQEnvironment.hostname = "192.168.120.28:1415";`.  Roger already provided an accepted answer explaining how to specify the port number properly 9 years ago.