# For Websphere MQ tutorial

Tags: java, websphere, ibm-mq, websphere-7

I am beginner in web sphere mq programming.

Any one has sample tutorial for connecting mq queue to java simple application.

***Basically i want to read a Mq queue through my java code.***

Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your RC=2538 is because you have a coding error and I already pointed it out in your other question at [MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2538'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21672833/mqje001-completion-code-2-reason-2538)

Secondly, there are 34 Java/MQ (non-JMS) sample MQ programs at http://www.capitalware.biz/mq_code_java.html

Have you reviewed any of them and/or tried them out?

Comment: yupp.. I have also try this code.Now i got this error=" 2539 (09EB) (RC2539): MQRC_CHANNEL_CONFIG_ERROR" I have tried a lot of but 2538 & 2539 error comming so i need a help. Thnaks again for given ur valuable time for me

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue??

Answer (score 3):

I find this tutorial and code in jboss site. It works as well. Try [this](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/SendMessagesToWebSphereMQ70) and enjoy.

```
public class WebSphereMQMessageSendServiceBean implements MessageSendService {


    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(WebSphereMQMessageSendServiceBean.class);
    private Connection connection = null;
    private Session session = null;
    private MessageProducer producer = null;


    public boolean sendMessage(String xmlMsg, String instrumentId) throws QueueServiceAdaptorException{
        boolean success = false;        
        String destinationType = "QUEUE";
        String destinationName = "PRO.QDX.QDX.MSG.QDC";
        String channel = "PROQDIB.SVRCONN";
        String hostName = "localhost";
        Integer port = "1414";
        String queueManager = "REFDMQ01";
        String uid = "nuwan";
        String provider = "com.ibm.msg.client.wmq";
        try {
            JmsFactoryFactory jmsFactoryFactory = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(WMQConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER);
            JmsConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory = jmsFactoryFactory.createConnectionFactory();
            // Set the properties
            jmsConnectionFactory.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_HOST_NAME, hostName);
            jmsConnectionFactory.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_PORT, port);
            jmsConnectionFactory.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL, channel);
            jmsConnectionFactory.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
            jmsConnectionFactory.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, queueManager);     


            // Create JMS objects
            connection = jmsConnectionFactory.createConnection();
            session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            Destination destination = null;
            if (destinationType.equals("QUEUE")) {
                destination = session.createQueue(destinationName);
            }
            else {
                destination = session.createTopic(destinationName);
            }
            producer = session.createProducer(destination);
            //connection.setExceptionListener(this);
            connection.start();
            TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage();
            // If WMQ_MESSAGE_BODY is set to WMQ_MESSAGE_BODY_MQ, no additional header is added to the message body. 
            ((MQDestination) destination).setMessageBodyStyle(WMQConstants.WMQ_MESSAGE_BODY_MQ);
            ((MQDestination)destination).setMQMDWriteEnabled(true);            
            message.setText(xmlMsg);
            message.setJMSCorrelationID(instrumentId);
            producer.send(message);
            success = true;
            logger.info("WebSphereMQMessageSender.sendMessage: Sent message:\n" + message);
        }
        catch (JMSException e) {
            logger.error("WebSphereMQMessageSender.sendMessage: JMSException while sending message to QDIB", e);
            success = false;
            recordFailure(e);
            throw new QueueServiceAdaptorException("WebSphereMQMessageSender.sendMessage: "
                    + "JMSException while sending message to QDIB", e);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("WebSphereMQMessageSender.sendMessage: Exception while sending message to QDIB", e);
            success = false;
            throw new QueueServiceAdaptorException("WebSphereMQMessageSender.sendMessage: "
                    + "Exception while sending message to QDIB", e);
        }
        finally {
            cleanUp();
        }
        return success;
    }


    /**
     * Record this run as failure.
     *
     * @param ex exception
     */
    private void recordFailure(Exception ex) {
        if (ex != null) {
            if (ex instanceof JMSException) {
                processJMSException((JMSException) ex);
            } else {
                logger.error("WebSphereMQMessageSender.recordFailure: " + ex);
            }
        }
        logger.error("WebSphereMQMessageSender.recordFailure: FAILURE");        
    }


    /**
     * Process a JMSException and any associated inner exceptions.
     *
     * @param jmsex jmsex
     */
    private void processJMSException(JMSException jmsex) {
        logger.error(jmsex);
        Throwable innerException = jmsex.getLinkedException();
        if (innerException != null) {
            logger.error("WebSphereMQMessageSender.processJMSException: Inner exception(s):");
        }
        while (innerException != null) {
            logger.error(innerException);
            innerException = innerException.getCause();
        }
    }


    /**
     * Release resources
     * */
    private void cleanUp() {
        if (producer != null) {
            try {
                producer.close();
            } catch (JMSException jmsex) {
                logger.error("WebSphereMQMessageSender. cleanUp: Producer could not be closed.");
                recordFailure(jmsex);
            }
        }
        if (session != null) {
            try {
                session.close();
            } catch (JMSException jmsex) {
                logger.error("WebSphereMQMessageSender. cleanUp: Session could not be closed.");
                recordFailure(jmsex);
            }
        }
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (JMSException jmsex) {
                logger.error("WebSphereMQMessageSender. cleanUp: Connection could not be closed.");
                recordFailure(jmsex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```